# Getting error "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Im getting the exception:

> Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Where am I wrong?

**code:**

```
try{

     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","root");
     Statement s=con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs1=s.executeQuery("Select * from items");

     while(rs1.next()) {
       q= (q+Integer.parseInt(rs1.getString("qty")));
       //update items Set qty=5 where name='Maggi';
       s.executeUpdate("update items SET qty="+q+" WHERE name='"+value+"'");
     }
}                                        
catch(Exception ee){
  System.out.println(ee);
}
```

Comment: You are using same `Statement` object twice. You need two different `Statement` Objects to execute query and update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you will need two different Statement Objects to execute the query and update parts try:

```
 try{

     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","root");enter code here
    Statement s=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1=s.executeQuery("Select * from items");

    while(rs1.next()){
       q= (q+Integer.parseInt(rs1.getString("qty")));
       s=con.createStatement();  // <- create a new statement here
       s.executeUpdate("update items SET qty="+q+" WHERE name='"+value+"'");
    }
 }                                        
 catch(Exception ee){
    System.out.println(ee);
 }
}
```

Also consider using a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and using `set*` method to avoid potential SQL Injection

Comment: Seriously? Just code, no explanations?

Comment: @Jägermeister - Sorry was called away - work to do and all that.